# simplexml_load_string equivalent Python / Django

Tags: python, xml, django, simplexml

I'm trying to find a xml-interpret function (like the simplexml_load_string) in Python, but with no success :/

Let's say I have xml in a string

```
my_xml_string = """
<root>
      <content>
        <one>A value</one>
        <two>Here goes for ...</two>
      </content>
</root>"""
```

To read an value in php I would normaly do something like this

```
// read into object
$xml = simplexml_load_string(my_xml_string);

// print some values
echo $xml->root->content->one
echo $xml->root->content->two
```

are there any equivalent object in python/django?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from xml.dom.minidom import *

```
my_xml_string = """
<root>
      <content>
        <one>A value</one>
        <two>Here goes for ...</two>
      </content>
</root>"""

xml = parseString(xml_string)
result = xml.getElementsByTagName('one')[0].firstChild.data
```

This did the trick, for now!

Answer (score 4):

The nearest is probably [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which is part of the python standard library (or an extended version [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/))

```
import  xml.etree

element =  xml.etree.ElementTree.XML(my_xml_string)
```

sets up element which is of class Element and this can be treated as lists of XML elements

e.g.

```
# for your example
print(element[0][0].tag)
print(element[0][0].text)
print(element[0][3].text)
```

You can also search by XPaths if you want to use names.

lxml also has an [objectify](http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify.html) model that allows access of elements as "if you were dealing with a normal Python object hierarchy." Which matches the php useage more exactly

Comment: Hmm what about xml.dom.minidom?

Comment: You could use that - but youare then manipularing a DOM - lxml and Element Tree try to make the navifaction more 'pythonic' not  DOM specific

Answer (score 2):

[lxml.objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) does exactly what you want

```
In [1]: from lxml import objectify

In [2]: x = objectify.fromstring("""<response><version>1.2</version><amount>1.01</amount><currency>USD</currency></response>""")

In [3]: x.version
Out[3]: 1.2

In [4]: x.amount
Out[4]: 1.01

In [5]: x.currency
Out[5]: 'USD'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html) includes several xml parsing modules. Probably the easiest is ElementTree.

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring(my_xml_string)

print xml.find('.//content/one').text
print xml.find('.//content/two').text
```

Answer (score 1):

[ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is quite common and is probably the best library included in Python (since version 2.5).

However, personally I prefer [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) for both power and flexibility. The "lxml.objectify" method is particularly useful for parsing large XML DOMs into pythonic objects.

Comment: I dont really like the ElementTree, maybe i'm a bit unused to the syntax. xml.dom.minidom seems more complete to me. I'll definitely look into lxml! Thanks!

Comment: minidom is the simplest, but also the *least* pythonic and the least feature-complete. I've used it to get the job done before, but if you spend much time working with XML you'll abandon it pretty soon.